# Only my application should have permission to access the files generated by app

Tags: android

My application generates some .csv files while running and these files are placed inside Android File system. These files are accessible outside the application also(as i can open these files in text editor and modify...)
**Now I want that only my application should be able to read/write into these files.
Please help me in achieving this.** 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can do it only if you store data in internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

> These files are accessible outside the application also(as i can open these files in text editor and modify...)

Presumably that means you are placing them on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> Now I want that only my application should be able to read/write into these files

Place the files on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). This will prevent ordinary Android users from accessing the files except via your app.

Owners of rooted devices can get at those files, and if you are concerned about that scenario, then do not create any files at all, as owners of rooted devices can get to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Also see article here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

It informs about internal vs external storage as well as making data public vs private for your app.